# make_shared create std::shared_ptr? gcc 4.6.2

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, gcc4, make-shared

i'm using gcc 4.6.2.

I'm trying to push_back in a vector shared_ptr's.

But gcc gives me everytime an error.

Here my codelines:

```
std::vector< std::tr1::shared_ptr<Process> > procs;
std::string line;
while (getline(file, line) && line.find(JobMask) != std::string::npos)
{
    std::string procName                      = line.substr(line.find(JobMask) + JobMask.size());
    std::vector<Instruction> procInstructions = extractProgram(file);
    std::queue<int>          procInputs       = extractInputs(file);

    if (!procInstructions.empty())
        procs.push_back(std::make_shared<Process>(Process(procName, procInputs, procInstructions))); //line 51
}
return procs;
```

The Error my gcc is giving is:

```
Process.cpp: In static member function 'static std::vector<std::tr1::shared_ptr<RMMIX::Process> > RMMIX::Process::createProcesses(const string&)':

Process.cpp:51:95: error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<std::tr1::shared_ptr<RMMIX::Process> >::push_back(std::shared_ptr<RMMIX::Process>)'

Process.cpp:51:95: note: candidates are:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.2/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_vector.h:826:7: note: void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = std::tr1::shared_ptr<RMMIX::Process>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::tr1::shared_ptr<RMMIX::Process> >, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = std::tr1::shared_ptr<RMMIX::Process>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.2/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_vector.h:826:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::shared_ptr<RMMIX::Process>' to 'const value_type& {aka const std::tr1::shared_ptr<RMMIX::Process>&}'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.2/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_vector.h:839:7: note: void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type&&) [with _Tp = std::tr1::shared_ptr<RMMIX::Process>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::tr1::shared_ptr<RMMIX::Process> >, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = std::tr1::shared_ptr<RMMIX::Process>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.2/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_vector.h:839:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::shared_ptr<RMMIX::Process>' to 'std::vector<std::tr1::shared_ptr<RMMIX::Process> >::value_type&& {aka std::tr1::shared_ptr<RMMIX::Process>&&}'
```

In my eyes the error say's, that std::make_shared create a std::shared_ptr.
But in gcc shared_ptr is in the namespace std::tr1.
How could i fix it?

Comment: `std::make_shared<T>(x...)` is equivalent to `std::shared_ptr<T>(new T(x...))` (without unnecessary ref-counts), so you should just call `std::make_shared<Process>(procName, procInputs, procInstructions)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand correctly, `make_shared` is new in C++11 and is in namespace `std`, but it is only available if you compile with `-std=gnu++0x` or similar. But if you do that, then `shared_ptr` is also in `std`.

The problem is that there is another version of `shared_ptr` in `std::tr1`, but in C++11 mode you should not use it: it should be considered *deprecated*.

Your solution is simply to remove every use of `tr1` and use the full C++11 version of these classes.

Comment: thx a lot :) 
i don't know that i could take the normal function.

Answer (score 3):

C++ template error message can be a beast to read.  But the answer is in the 2nd note.

```
no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::shared_ptr<RMMIX::Process>' to 'const value_type& {aka const std::tr1::shared_ptr<RMMIX::Process>&}'
```

The problem is you're using `std::make_shared` (which creates a `std::shared_ptr`) and passing it into a vector of `std::tr1::shared_ptr`.

The simplest solution is drop the TR1.  The stuff from the TR1 was some of first features implemented by compilers when adding C++11 support.

```
std::vector< std::shared_ptr<Process> > procs;
```

If you are unable to stop using `std::tr1::shared_ptr`.  You'll have to forgo using `make_shared` as it was not part of the TR1.

Comment: I have written my own make_shared's in toy projects that needed to work with tr1 libraries. Is there any pitfall in doing so?

Comment: `make_shared` is more than a wrapper on the `shared_ptr` ctor. It relies on internal details to put the metadata with the type in one allocation. You need to ensure your version is compatible both implementations, which wont be portable between anything (compilers, compiler version, days of the week).

Comment: Thanks. I wouldn't expect compatibility down to such details, just convenience when not always using a recently-released compiler.